# Query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL statement:

```
SELECT        ASIN, Date, DateSoldActualized, FNSKU, ItemName, MaxShipmentDateAllSkus,    MaxShipmentDateThisSKU, MerchantID, MerchantSKU, SoldIn30Days, TotalQty
FROM            AmazonSKUs
WHERE        (MerchantSKU LIKE @MerchantSKU)
```

I have a large database with 20,000 records. 72 of those record have a MerchantSKU that start with MEA_. When I search by MEA_% I get nothing. I have roughly 100 records that start withe ACD_. When I query by ACD_% I get 10 records Whether I used my program I am writing to display this data or run the query against my db directly.

To execute this  I call a function from my GUI:

`s.createdisplay(txtSellerSku.Text.Trim()+"_%");`

which in turns calls this function which build a couple of `List<string>`'s:

`inventory.AmazonSKUsDataTable builder = i.GetbySKU(sellersku);`

which call this function from my bll which actually runs my query:

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
    (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public inventory.AmazonSKUsDataTable GetbySKU(string SKU)
    {
        return Adatper.GetbySKU(SKU);
    }
```

So here is my question why does that query not work?

Edit: Here are a couple rows of my data

`MerchantID MerchantSKU Date TotalQty SoldIn30Days ASIN  SELECT        ASIN, Date, DateSoldActualized FNSKU ItemName MaxShipmentDateAllSkus MaxShipmentDateThisSKU ItemName Rank Price Amazon`

`A1B7M9EQGNCLQA MEA_89930_C6.39 6/3/2011 6:35:07 PM 47  6/3/2011 6:35:07 PM 0   B0020OWVDS  6/3/2011 6:35:07 PM 6/3/2011 6:35:07 PM X0006J5C9F  NULL    NULL    Medela TheraShells Breast Shells #89930 [Baby Product]  8,902  Baby 24.99   F`

`A1B7M9EQGNCLQA MEA_89973_C2.60 5/10/2011 12:00:00 AM   69  5/15/2011 12:00:00 AM   37  B00006FWVO  5/15/2011 12:00:00 AM   5/8/2011 12:00:00 AM    B00006FWVO  NULL    NULL    Medela Disposable Nursing Bra Pads - 30-pk [Baby Product]   2,603  Baby 9.07    F`

`A1B7M9EQGNCLQA MEA_89974   5/10/2011 12:00:00 AM   3   5/15/2011 12:00:00 AM   52  B00006FWVR  5/15/2011 12:00:00 AM   5/2/2011 12:00:00 AM    B00006FWVR  NULL    NULL    Medela Disposable Nursing Bra Pads - 60-pk. [Baby Product]  734  Baby   12.01   F`

Comment: @yosef 20k records is a small db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_` character is the "replace by one arbitrary character" wildcard in SQL - much like `?` in DOS/Windows.

Try to do a `.. WHERE MerchantSKU LIKE 'MEA%'` - do you get anything back now?

If you must use the underscore, try putting it into square brackets:

```
.. WHERE MerchantSKU LIKE 'MEA[_]%'
```

**Update:** I cannot reproduce your problems - at least not on the SQL Server level - try this yourself:

```
DECLARE @merchant TABLE (MerchantID VARCHAR(50), MerchantSKU VARCHAR(50), TotalQty INT)

INSERT INTO @merchant
VALUES('A1B7M9EQGNCLQA', 'MEA_89930_C6.39', 47),
('A1B7M9EQGNCLQA', 'MEA_89973_C2.60', 69),
('A1B7M9EQGNCLQA', 'MEA_89974', 3),
('X1B7M9EQGNCLQA', 'MEB_89930_C6.39', 4711),
('X1B7M9EQGNCLQA', 'MEF_89930_C6.39', 42),
('X1B7M9EQGNCLQA', 'MEZ_89930_C6.39', 7)

SELECT *
FROM @merchant
WHERE MerchantSKU LIKE 'MEA[_]%'
```

According to my testing, the proper rows are all found and returned. I suspect there's something in the code that actually *calls* your SQL query that's "fishy" and causes these problems - the SQL statement as such is valid and works.

Comment: Here is the unique part if I remove or escape it my result do not change.

Comment: I showed some rows, I am not sure what you mean by whole query

Comment: @Joe Tyman: probably put that into a new question for best results !

Comment: I was using a try catch to catch nulls and instead of just catching the one record and moving on, it caught my whole loop through my data table.

Answer (score 2):

`'_'` in LIKE comparison means in sql any single character. this could be the problem.

you could use it with escape:

```
where myvalue like 'MEA[_]%'
```

Look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized queries like below structure. so no need to  enclose underscore with square brackets or no need to join single quote with quote.

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) { 
    con.Open(); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
    string expression = "Parameter value"; 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", 
                SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;    
    cmd.Connection = con; 
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        if (dr.Read()) 
        { 
        } 
    } 
}
```